# Print Pdf with CSS

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I am Developing a website in symfony framework.In my application I want to print the page in Pdf format.I have Successfully print the page using SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle.The problem is that my page is printed without Css.I dont Know how can I print the page with css in pdf.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **media="print"**  while adding your stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="style.css">
```